# Another word for ensure but less absolute

Tags: synonyms

I need a word that essentially means I'm going to try my best, but sounds a bit more optimistic.
Here's the sentence for context:
I hope to make universal design the standard practice and _____ no person feels excluded from an activity, commodity, or opportunity due to a lack of representative design.

Answer (score 1):

The word *promote* is less absolute than *ensure*, but it won't fit your sentence. What would make your sentence make sense would be to drop the *and* and insert *so that*.
The lesser level of certainty will be carried over from the earlier phrase *hope to make*.

> I hope to make universal design the standard practice so that no person feels excluded from an activity, commodity, or opportunity due to a lack of representative design.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but I'd like to add a suggestion. You can eliminate the *and* and use *towards ensuring*.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope to make universal design the standard practice and **see** / **see to it** that
> no person feels excluded from an activity, commodity, or opportunity
> due to a lack of representative design.

**see** (v.)

> To ensure, be mindful, take care that something happens, that someone
> does something, etc. OED
>
> *Mrs. Lavender would see that she was properly looked after.*
>
> *See she gets this, could you?*

**see to it** (idiom)

> To make sure that something is done
>
> *Can you see to it that everyone gets a copy of this memo?* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see%20to%20it)

---

> He **saw** to my care personally, focusing fully on my needs. [Aditi
> Goel; *Playing at Cancer at Age 13*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Playing_with_Cancer_at_Age_13/eDDMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=He%20personally%20saw%20to%20my%20care&pg=PT62&printsec=frontcover)

> He not only guided us to Del Rio, but he personally **saw to it** that
> my wife and I were taken care of. [Richard Lewis; *The Journey of a
> Post-Modern Missionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Journey_of_a_Post_Modern_Missionary/xeCg6m7kSrUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=personally%20saw%20that%20were%20taken%20care%20of&pg=PA29&printsec=frontcover)

*See to it that [something]* sounds a little more certain than *see that [something].*